# Issue with User Data Isolation and Session Management in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, session, cookies, authorization

I'm encountering a problem in my ASP.NET Core 6 application related to user data isolation and session management. My goal is to ensure that each user has their own session and that session data is isolated from one user to another. However, even after logging out, I noticed that previous user data and links are accessible when a new user logs in. This behavior is not expected.

Here's a breakdown of my application's setup:

I'm using ASP.NET Core 6.
I have implemented authentication and authorization using the Cookie authentication scheme.
I have added session management using AddSession.
I have tried to clear session data and cookies upon user logout, but the issue persists.
My code snippets:

Session Configuration in Program.cs:

csharp

// Add services to the container.

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

Logout Action in a Controller:

csharp

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
{
    HttpContext.Session.Clear();
    HttpContext.Session.Remove("UserSettings");
    HttpContext.Session.Remove("UserPreferences");
    HttpContext.Session.Remove("UID");

    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var cookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies;
    foreach (var key in cookies.Keys)
    {
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(key);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
}
```

What I've tried:

Clearing session data and cookies upon user logout.
Checking the authentication status to ensure the user is logged out.
Question:

How can I ensure complete user data isolation, where a new user cannot access any data or links of a previously logged-out user?
What might be causing the issue of previous user data persisting across different sessions?
Are there any best practices or configuration changes I should make for proper user session management in ASP.NET Core 6?
I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or code changes to help resolve this issue. Thank you!

What I've Tried:

I've implemented session management in my ASP.NET Core 6 application using AddSession with an idle timeout of 15 minutes.
Upon user logout in my controller's LogOut action, I've attempted to clear session data using `HttpContext.Session.Clear()`, and I've also removed specific session keys related to user settings, preferences, and user IDs.
In the LogOut action, I've used await `HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)` to sign out the user.
To ensure the removal of cookies, I've iterated through the cookies using HttpContext.Request.Cookies and deleted them using `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(key)`.
Expected Behavior:

After a user logs out, I expected all their session data, including user-specific settings and preferences, to be completely cleared.
I expected the user to be signed out and the authentication information to be removed so that they couldn't access their previous data or any protected links after a new user logs in.
Actual Result:

Despite my efforts to clear session data and cookies upon user logout, I noticed that when a new user logs in, they can access the previous user's data and links. This behavior is unexpected and poses a security risk.

Comment: `that previous user data and links are accessible when a new user logs in` could you pls explain this symptom? in my humble opinion, session should be isolated by default....

Comment: We have asp.net core [session statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#session-state) here.